# Crayon Syntax Highlighter for WordPress looks bad on AMP pages

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting, amp-html

I have a WordPress blog about computer science and the problem is that the Crayon Syntax Highlighter sequences look like this on AMP pages:

[image]

So they are doubled. How can I remove the first part (this one which is resizable)? I saw this thing on almost all AMP websites that are using this plug-in, and I think it's a big problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first part is the plain version of the code that you're syntax-highlighting, and it's in a `textarea` box/field *inside* a `div` with the class `crayon-plain-wrap`:

```
<div class="crayon-plain-wrap">
  <textarea wrap="soft" class="crayon-plain ..." ...>
    plain/non-formatted code here...
  </textarea>
</div>
```

**How to disable that box**

1. ***Easiest option***: Just visit the plugin settings page (Settings -> Crayon), find the "*Enable plain code view and display*" field under the General -> Code section on that page, and just uncheck the option/checkbox..
2. **Use custom CSS to hide the `div`** *when the request is the AMP version of the current page*.

   - If you use the [AMP](https://amp-wp.org) plugin, you can add the CSS programmatically like so: (add this to the theme's `functions.php` file)

     ```
     add_action( 'amp_post_template_css', function(){
         echo '.crayon-plain-wrap { display: none; }';
     } );
     ```

     or copy just the CSS code (i.e. `.crayon-plain-wrap { display: none; }`) and put it in an appropriate place.

**Using other AMP plugin?**

Just try to implement the *second* option above with that plugin...

But do let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you! I used the second option because the first one leads to the disappearance of the "copy" button from the code snippets.

Comment: You're very welcome. And I'd actually choose the same option. :)